# Not able to convert this SQL query to PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

The question is to retrieve all the students name who have scored more than average marks. So, As i am familiar in SQL i have came up with this query:

```
SELECT Student_Name
FROM Student
WHERE Mark >  
( SELECT AVG(Mark)  
FROM Student
);
```

But i need this query to be in PL/SQL format. Please help me.

Comment: Why do you need to put this into as stored procedure?

Comment: Sir @a_horse_with_no_name, I am learning PL/SQL.

Comment: The question is rather what you intend to do with PLSQL ?

Comment: If you are learning PL/SQL, start by reading the _PL/SQL Language Reference_ which is part of the Oracle database documentation and is available online. Make sure you read the one that suits the version of Oracle that you are using. After that, you could visit this Web site: https://www.stevenfeuerstein.com/

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do, once you convert it to PL/SQL. In PL/SQL, you have to fetch the result *into* something. For example (based on Scott's schema):

```
SQL> select ename
  2  from emp
  3  where sal > (select avg(sal) from emp);

ENAME
----------
JONES
BLAKE
CLARK
SCOTT
KING
FORD

6 rows selected.
```

---

You could select into an array:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_tab sys.odcivarchar2list;
  3  begin
  4    select ename
  5      bulk collect into l_tab
  6      from emp
  7      where sal > (select avg(sal) from emp);
  8
  9    for i in l_tab.first .. l_tab.last loop
 10      dbms_output.put_line(l_tab(i));
 11    end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /
JONES
BLAKE
CLARK
SCOTT
KING
FORD

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Or, you can process those rows directly in a loop:

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_e in (select ename
  3                  from emp
  4                  where sal > (select avg(sal) from emp))
  5    loop
  6      dbms_output.put_line(cur_e.ename);
  7    end loop;
  8  end;
  9  /
JONES
BLAKE
CLARK
SCOTT
KING
FORD

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Or, you can make a function out of it and return refcursor:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for select ename
  7                from emp
  8                where sal > (select avg(sal) from emp);
  9    return rc;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

ENAME
----------
JONES
BLAKE
CLARK
SCOTT
KING
FORD

6 rows selected.


SQL>
```

---

There might be other options as well. Basically, it just depends on the requirement.